# lodash collection - add extra custom property in existing objects of collection

Tags: javascript, json, object, lodash

This is my first time using lodash and I'm trying to figure out how to update each record within a JSON object. For example, let's say I have a person object:

```
"person":[
  {
    "firstName" : "Alex",
    "lastName" : "Smith"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Madison",
    "lastName" : "Matthews"
  }
]
```

I would like to add a new field called "fullName" to each record in person that is a combination of their first and last names. Is there a way I can do this using lodash and/or javascript? I don't want to use any other tool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here if you have persons collection(Array of json objects) then you can add one more property by traversing the collection with lodash function. There are other several ways also.

```
var persons = [
  {
    "firstName" : "Alex",
    "lastName" : "Smith"
  },
  {
    "firstName" : "Madison",
    "lastName" : "Matthews"
  }
];

var personsWithFullName = _(persons).forEach(function(person) {
      person.fullName = person.firstName + person.lastName;
     return person;
});
```

or

```
var newPersonsWithFullName = _.map(persons , function(person) { 
     return _.assign({}, person, {fullName: (person.firstName + person.lastName)});
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked. Thank you so much! Also, thanks for teaching me the correct terminology to use as well (kind of a newbie at all of this). Appreciate it!